# TYPO3 activating rte for an input field (textarea)

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, rte

6 extension I want to activate the RTE for some textarea fields.

My TCA looks like this:

```
 'aufgaben' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:justo/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_justo_domain_model_stelle.aufgaben',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'text',
                'cols' => 40,
                'rows' => 15,
                'eval' => 'trim',
                'enableRichtext' => true
            ],
            'defaultExtras' => 'richtext:rte_transform[mode=ts_css]'
        ],
```

like its mentioned in the docs https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/Rte/InTheBackend/Introduction/Index.html

This should be enough to enable the RTE `The short story is that it's enough to set the key enableRichtext to true.`

But RTE is not displayed ...

Whats my fail?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE Full TCA**

```
<?php
return [
    'ctrl' => [
        'title' => 'LLL:EXT:justo/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_justo_domain_model_stelle',
        'label' => 'titel',
        'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
        'crdate' => 'crdate',
        'cruser_id' => 'cruser_id',
        'versioningWS' => true,
        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
        'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
        'transOrigDiffSourceField' => 'l10n_diffsource',
        'delete' => 'deleted',
        'enablecolumns' => [
            'disabled' => 'hidden',
            'starttime' => 'starttime',
            'endtime' => 'endtime',
        ],
        'searchFields' => 'titel,aufgaben,profil,erwartungen,ort,beginn,stellung,raum',
        'iconfile' => 'EXT:justo/Resources/Public/Icons/tx_justo_domain_model_stelle.gif'
    ],
    'interface' => [
        'showRecordFieldList' => 'sys_language_uid, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource, hidden, titel, aufgaben, profil, erwartungen, ort, beginn, stellung, raum',
    ],
    'types' => [
        '1' => ['showitem' => 'sys_language_uid, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource, hidden, titel, aufgaben;;;richtext:rte_transform[mode=ts_links], profil, erwartungen, ort, beginn, stellung, raum, --div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access, starttime, endtime'],
    ],
    'columns' => [
        'sys_language_uid' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.language',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                'special' => 'languages',
                'items' => [
                    [
                        'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.allLanguages',
                        -1,
                        'flags-multiple'
                    ]
                ],
                'default' => 0,
            ],
        ],
        'l10n_parent' => [
            'displayCond' => 'FIELD:sys_language_uid:>:0',
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.l18n_parent',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                'items' => [
                    ['', 0],
                ],
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_justo_domain_model_stelle',
                'foreign_table_where' => 'AND tx_justo_domain_model_stelle.pid=###CURRENT_PID### AND tx_justo_domain_model_stelle.sys_language_uid IN (-1,0)',
            ],
        ],
        'l10n_diffsource' => [
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ],
        ],
        't3ver_label' => [
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.versionLabel',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'max' => 255,
            ],
        ],
        'hidden' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.hidden',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'check',
                'items' => [
                    '1' => [
                        '0' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_core.xlf:labels.enabled'
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'starttime' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.starttime',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 13,
                'eval' => 'datetime',
                'default' => 0,
            ]
        ],
        'endtime' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.endtime',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 13,
                'eval' => 'datetime',
                'default' => 0,
                'range' => [
                    'upper' => mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2038)
                ]
            ],
        ],
        'titel' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:justo/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_justo_domain_model_stelle.titel',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ],
        ],
        'aufgaben' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:justo/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_justo_domain_model_stelle.aufgaben',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'text',
                'cols' => 40,
                'rows' => 15,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ],
            'defaultExtras' => 'richtext:rte_transform[flag=rte_enabled|mode=ts]',
        ],
        'profil' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:justo/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_justo_domain_model_stelle.profil',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'text',
                'cols' => 40,
                'rows' => 15,
                'eval' => 'trim',
            ],
            'defaultExtras' => 'richtext:rte_transform[mode=ts_css]'
        ],
        'erwartungen' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:justo/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_justo_domain_model_stelle.erwartungen',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'text',
                'cols' => 40,
                'rows' => 15,
                'eval' => 'trim',
            ],
            'defaultExtras' => 'richtext:rte_transform[mode=ts_css]'
        ],
        'ort' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:justo/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_justo_domain_model_stelle.ort',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ],
        ],
        'beginn' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:justo/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_justo_domain_model_stelle.beginn',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ],
        ],
        'stellung' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:justo/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_justo_domain_model_stelle.stellung',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ],
        ],
        'raum' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:justo/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_justo_domain_model_stelle.raum',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: which version of TYPO3 ?

Comment: Did you have RTE elsewhere in this TYPO3 installation?

Comment: for sure in text and media elements for example

Comment: Note "enableRichtext" has been introduced in v8 (not core v7) to simplify the RTE configuration mess down to one simple trigger. That's why this flag does not work in v7.

Comment: oh okay, and is there a way to use it in v7?

Comment: You can change documentation to the needed version. In the navigation column at the bottom the TYPO3 version can be switched: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/7.6/Rte/InTheBackend/Index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
'types' => [
    '1' => ['showitem' => '
        ...,
        aufgaben;;;richtext:rte_transform[mode=ts_links],
        ...,
    '],
],
...
'columns' => [  
    'aufgaben' => [
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:justo/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_justo_domain_model_stelle.aufgaben',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'text',
            'cols' => 80,
            'rows' => 15,
            'eval' => 'trim',
        ],
        'defaultExtras' => 'richtext:rte_transform[flag=rte_enabled|mode=ts]',
    ],
],
```

Comment: does not change anything. I've added the whole TCA above.

Comment: In TYPO3 7 TCA is cached. Did you remove all caches?